# Reduce Formula size

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have logic in Account object for Formula field, but while i try to save it gives me error

> Error: Compiled formula is too big to execute (6,387 characters).
>   Maximum size is 5,000 characters

Below is my code:

```
IF(
    AND(
        ISPICKVAL(Campaign.FCRM__FCR_Campaign_Sourced_By__c, 'Marketing'),
        OR(TAL__c = True, Tele_Rejected__c = True)), 'Marketing',
    IF(
        OR(
            AND(
                ISPICKVAL(Campaign.FCRM__FCR_Campaign_Sourced_By__c, 'Marketing'),

                OR(
                    TAL__c = False,
                    Tele_Rejected__c = False),
                OR(
                    Oppy_Last_30_Days_On_Create__c > 0,
                    Country = 'Canada',
                    Country = 'Mexico',
                    Theater__c = 'APAC',
                    AND(Theater__c = 'EMEA',
                        OR(Country = 'United Kingdom',
                            Country = 'Germany',
                            Country = 'France',
                            Country = 'Sweden',
                            Country = 'Norway',
                            Country = 'Finland',
                            Country = 'Denmark',
                            Country = 'The Netherlands',
                            Country = 'Belgium',
                            Country = 'Luxembourg',
                            Country = 'Ireland')
                    ),
                    Account_Type_on_Create__c = 'Active Prospect',
                    Account_Type_On_Update__c = 'Active Prospect',
                    Sales_Rejected__c = True,
                    Sales_Engaged__c = True,
                    ISPICKVAL(Contact.Account.Type, 'Client'),
                    ISBLANK(Contact.SA__c)
                )
            ),
            TEXT(Contact.Owner.Sales_Responsibilities__c) = "AM"), 'Marketing-RA',
        IF(
            AND(
                ISPICKVAL(Campaign.FCRM__FCR_Campaign_Sourced_By__c, 'Marketing'),
                TAL__c = False,
                FCRM__FCR_SAR__c = True), 'Marketing-RA',
            IF(
                ISPICKVAL(Campaign.FCRM__FCR_Campaign_Sourced_By__c, 'Marketing'), 'Marketing',
                '')
        )
    )
)
```

Can anyone suggest how to reduce this formula?

Comment: Given that the text you have posted is about 2k long, some of the fields you are using must also be formula fields so consider those usages. See [Tips for Reducing Formula Size](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/8/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_formula_size_tipsheet.pdf).

Comment: Hi Keith, Thanks for reply but in my case there are no formula fields in this formula, and how can i reduce this formula. Can you give some idea?

Comment: Help us in order to be helped. There are some cross-referenced conditions in the formula (or at least how I see them), and please double check what field(s) is/are a formula

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if these changes will be enough to get this specific formula under the compile size limit, but here are some ways to bring it down:

**Don't compare Boolean/checkbox fields to TRUE/FALSE.** Use just the field name, or NOT(field_name__c). In a quick test on a checkbox field Inactive__c:

- IF(Inactive__c,"Active","Inactive") - compiled size 75 chars
- IF(NOT(Inactive__c),"Inactive","Active") - compiled size 81 chars
- IF(Inactive__c = TRUE,"Active","Inactive") - compiled size 107 chars
- IF(Inactive__c = FALSE,"Inactive","Active") - compiled size 107 chars

**Reduce repeated calls to fields.** If I'm reading things correctly, this formula will only return a non-blank value when Campaign.FCRM__FCR_Campaign_Sourced_By__c is 'Marketing'. So make that check a single element of an IF and then put the rest in, rather than checking for it at each point.

**Don't check field superfluously.** Unless there are cases where Theater__c != EMEA AND one of the named European Countries is specified, you can take that check for EMEA out.

Finally, while referencing other formula fields won't help, as a last resort you can create new custom fields directly on the object where the formula is and populate them with workflow or Process Builder. The Campaign.FCRM__FCR_Campaign_Sourced_By__c field might be a good candidate for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can decrease the size of your formula by breaking it into multiple formulas.  For instance, you could create a separate formula field called Country_Tier__c with the following formula:

```
 CASE(Country,  
    'United Kingdom', 1,
    'Germany', 1,
    'France', 1,
    'Sweden', 1,
    'Norway', 1,
    'Finland', 1,
    'Denmark', 1,
    'The Netherlands', 1,
    'Belgium', 1,
    'Luxembourg', 1,
    'Ireland', 1,
    2)
```

Then, you can reference the answer to this formula in your original formula.

Comment: This approach does *not* help with Compiled Size.